# How can I reposition a DIV with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to use AJAX (not jQuery)....
I basically have this going on.

```
Content A Title
Content A Full
HR
Content B Teaser
Content C Teaser
Content D Teaser
```

[Html/CSS Example of State A](http://jsfiddle.net/wJhuF/1/)

I have the before and after CSS, but I'm having trouble finding example code that actually alters CSS.  Instead, I'm finding tricks like 'adding a class' and stuff that people use to simply hack the CSS.  So, I think maybe I'm starting in the wrong place.

I'm using Php 5 and MySQL, if you want to be really helpful.  I'm not worried about that, though, as I'm presently working on it, myself.  What I'm SUPER interested in is figuring out how to create this, without having the page refresh:

```
Content C Title
Content C Full
HR
Content A Teaser
Content B Teaser
Content D Teaser
```

[HTML/CSS Example of State B](http://jsfiddle.net/wJhuF/2/)

Comment: This needs a LOT more detail before anyone can answer it. What are you using Ajax to do at the moment? Your example appears to be markup (e.g HTML) but you're talking about modifying the CSS. Is there any way you can make this clearer, either with concrete example, or by altering the wording?

Comment: I think when you say Ajax, you mean Javascript.  Nowadays the term ajax usually means contacting a server (using Javascript) to get data without reloading the page. And yes, as bobby says, it's not so clear what you'd like to know...

Comment: Where are you using ajax and for what? What do you mean by "Before and after css"? Please make the explicit sequence of steps you are doing to get from state A to state B

Comment: @Bobby Jack: It would be CSS, I believe.  I'm using CSS to position the DIV's on the page.

Comment: @150PoundOfDonamite I'm not sure what's unclear, though.  The client-side action, maybe?  If the user clicks 'Content C Teaser' from figure 1, it should return figure 2 without page refresh.  Also, JavierlEH... is that enough info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[element.setAttribute][1]("*style*", "*value*")`.  You can target the CSS `[document.querySelector][2]("*target*")` to select the div class or id or what-have-you.

You can use jQuery, like so: `$('*target*').css('*style*', '*value*')`.

There doesn't seem to be a short-hand AJAX equivalent.

Sample arguments:

```
Style: "align", "background-color".
Value: "center", "blue".

Target: "#myDiv", ".myDiv", "p"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like [THIS](http://www.elliotswan.com/2006/04/12/move-and-copy/). It is possible with Javascript to copy DOM elements or move them... Read something about cloning and deleting nodes with JS(clone node method described [HERE](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/cloneNode))

Comment: That's tight.  You should really put some code or a permanent bin link up in your answer, man.  Anyway.  Thumbs up.  I'll leave it open until I test it, of course.  Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry I really dont have time to do some samples in work :-) but the essence is to clone your node to some var, delete it and then re-insert it to other place...

Comment: I'm sorry.  I just can't seem to figure out how it works.  Interesting, though.

Comment: Please expand your answer so that it can stand on its own if either link happens to break. Otherwise, it may be removed.